# Nginx run from docker-compose returns "host not found in upstream"

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a reverse proxy towards an app by using nginx with this docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx_cloud:
    build: './nginx-cloud'
    ports:
        - 443:443
        - 80:80
    networks:
        - mynet
    depends_on:
        - app

  app:
    build: './app'
    expose:
        - 8000
    networks:
        - mynet

networks:
    mynet:
```

And this is my nginx conf (shortened):

```
 server {
  listen 80;
  server_name reverse.internal;

  location / {
    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    try_files $uri @to_app;
  }

  location @pto_app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app:8000;
  }
 }
```

When I run it, nginx returns:

```
[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:39
```

[I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122870/docker-nginx-reverse-proxy-host-not-found-in-upstream-when-building-with-doc) [tried](https://www.domysee.com/blogposts/reverse-proxy-nginx-docker-compose) [several](https://robertbasic.com/blog/docker-nginx-host-not-found-in-upstream-error/) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616166/nginx-and-docker-compose-host-not-found-in-upstream) [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717835/docker-proxy-pass-to-another-container-nginx-host-not-found-in-upstream) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720618/docker-nginx-stopped-emerg-11-host-not-found-in-upstream) [without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362558/docker-nginx-host-not-found-in-upstream) [any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717835/docker-proxy-pass-to-another-container-nginx-host-not-found-in-upstream) [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56680667/docker-nginx-host-not-found-in-upstream-in-docker). Curiously if I run nginx manually via shell access from inside the container it works, I can ping *app* etc. But running it from *docker-compose* or directly via *docker* itself, doesn't work.

I tried setting up a separate upstream, adding the docker internal resolver, waiting a few seconds to be sure the app is running already etc with no luck. I know this question has been asked several times, but nothing seems to work so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following server definition?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  reverse.*;

    location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

        set $target http://app:8080;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass $target;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, now I don't get the error anymore but nginx exits immediately with: "nginx_cloud exited with code 0" both from docker-compose or running it through docker directly. Logs show no activity of sort.

Comment: Ok this doesn't really solve it but it helped as nginx doesn't seem to timeout when a variable is used (??) so that pointed me in another direction: rebooting my computer. Something non-obvious happened to docker and rebooting solved it. Also it wasn't a matter of order of loading as the app loads near-instantly (and I had a wait-for-it.sh added to nginx just to be sure of loading nginx after the app). Thanks you and to Maxim.

Answer (score 1):

The `app` service may not start in time.
To diagnose the issue, try 2-step approach:

```
docker-compose up -d app
```

wait 15-20 seconds (or whatever it takes for the app to be up and ready)

```
docker-compose up -d nginx_cloud
```

If it works, then you have to update `entrypoint` in `nginx_cloud` service to wait for the `app` service.